# Allow users to print protected worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, printing, protected

I have a worksheet that is populated from userform information, and from a few other spreadsheets in the same file. I have used the following code:

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show
```

I ensure the sheet is activated before printing, and I have gotten the function working correctly.

This sheet and others in the workbook must be protected to prevent changes by the user outside of a userform. When I protect the sheet and add appropriate code to unlock that sheet a few things happen:
1. The userform is filled as designed.
2. The print dialog box shows up as designed.
3. When the print button is pressed on the dialog box, **it will not print**. Not a printer issue: It will not print to PDF either.

How can I get it to actually print the worksheet like I need?

Answer (score 0):

You can unprotect the sheet by using

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.unprotect

Then protect it after working with it using

```
ActiveSheet.Protect
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.protect

Answer (score 0):

banal code below must do the work without need to unprotect and protect

```
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Preview:=True, Collate:=True
```